# Script at specified location: scripts/stop_server.sh run as user root failed with exit code 126

Tags: amazon-web-services, pipeline, aws-code-deploy, aws-codepipeline

I am using aws codepipeline with aws code deploy, during deployment i am facing an error.

```sh
Error code: ScriptFailed
Script name: scripts/stop_server.sh
Message: Script at specified location: scripts/stop_server.sh run as user root failed with exit code 126
```

Logs:

```sh
LifecycleEvent - ApplicationStop
Script - scripts/stop_server.sh
[stderr]bash: /opt/codedeploy-agent/deployment-root/50b0321b-9518-42bf-bdf5-6dfde87c2c04/d-HPNVZMNRZ/deployment-archive/scripts/stop_server.sh: /bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

Comment: what is inside the stop_server.sh file? Can you show this?

Comment: #!/bin/bash
service httpd stop

This script is running as sudo.